# Doing multiple add_row() is slow

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I’m trying to do add approximately 200 rows in a ACF repeater field using add_row(). The following is my code. It works, but times out after a few minutes having added approx half of them. In other words it's slow.

```
    // Array with import data
    $rows = array (
      array(1,2,3),
      array(1,2,3),
      array(1,2,3)
    );

    // Loop to add it to the repeater field
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
      $row = array(
        'value1'    => $row[0],
        'value2'    => $row[1],
        'value3'    => $row[2]
      );

    add_row('repeater_field', $row, 40);
    }
```

Any suggestions to better ways to go about it?

Comment: What is `add_row`?

Comment: It's a Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)-specific function for adding rows in repeater fields..

Comment: If that's slow, then this code will be slow. There's nothing in your example here that's intrinsically slow, though.

Comment: Have you found the solution for the same